# Tensorflow 2.0 : Variables in Saved model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Is the variables files saved by saved_model API in protocol buffer (pb) format? If not, is there a way to load this without using tensorflow APIs( restore/ load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pure Python API which doesn't use TensorFlow operations if that's helpful: [list variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/list_variables) and [load a single variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/train/load_variable). For a SavedModel you can point those at the variables/ subdirectory.

There's also [TensorBundle](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3f23f4ddeabbdc0704444d84c158bd6c348a9f10/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle/tensor_bundle.h) which is the implementation in C++.

If neither of those are helpful the answer is probably "no". Theoretically it could be spun off into a separate package; if you're interested in doing that feel free to reach out.

Comment: Hi Allen, Thanks for the suggestions. I am looking for options to load tensors in variables file on a embedded system with minimal dependencies. Currently the best solution is frozen graph, which involves additional conversation step on saved model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.keras.models.load_model` to load a model from saved_model and what you get is a `tf.keras.Model` object.

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure if it is verified. but it seems like pointing The list_variables and load_variable to variables subdirectory of SavedModel is not working. we will see "checkpoint" file missed assert.
 a WA is to create a checkpoint file with one line pointed to the data file name.
model_checkpoint_path: "variables"